# RxJava2 concat() runs only the first Observable

Tags: java, android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have 3 methods which return `Observable(String)`. I need to perform this methods one by one. For each method neccessary approximately 2 or 3 minutes. I am using the next code:

```
Observable.concat(one(),two(),three())
          .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(String s) {
                        LOG.debug(s);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        LOG.error(e.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
```

Only the first method is performed. The second and the third method are ignored. I can't understand what is the problem? I am using RxJava2 version 2.1.6

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, `one()` is an `Observable` which does **not** emit `onComplete()` event, which means, that it has not yet finished, whereas `concat()` operator will wait until observable emits a terminal event and only then will start with the next observable.

If you do not possess the creation logics of first observable, you convert the observable into a `Single` using [`Single.fromObservable()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#fromObservable-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-) API.

```
Observable.concat(Single.fromObservable(one()), two(), three())
```

If you do have access to the creation logics of first observable, then emit a terminal event (i.e. [`emitter.onComplete()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#create-io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe-)).

---

As outlined by David Karnok in the comments sections:

> `Single.fromObservable()` also requires a completing source so it can error you if that source happens to have no items.

Comment: `Single.fromObservable()` also [requires a completing source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/observable/ObservableSingleSingle.java#L99) so it can error you if that source happens to have no items.

Comment: It may be works but for my situation I caught the error because of every method sends 8-10 requests and onNext method starts early than all requests are finished for every method..I found only one decision using zip and change some part of program.

Answer (score 2):

Is your first observable completing or is only emitting an item? According to the [docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) it won't emit items from two or three until after one completes.

Comment: My first observable only emitting an item and i can't understand how to continue work?

Comment: Call `onComplete`in your sources to allow `concat` to continue with the next.

Comment: It possible, but no so good. I found only one decision using zip and change some part of program.